# Получить оригинальную ссылку в vk api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте.

Решил для себя написать скрипт, который ищет посты с ключевыми словами в VK. Для этого я воспользовался следующим [методом](http://vk.com/dev/newsfeed.search) VK API. Хочется также уметь получать ссылку на оригинальный пост. Есть ли какие-то удобные средства, чтобы это сделать?

Сейчас написано, мягко говоря, костыльно:

```
    resp = requests.get(url).json()['response']
    for i in range(1, len(resp)):
      if (resp[i]['reposts']['count'] > 10):
        curId = resp[i]['owner_id']
        club = ""
        if (curId >= 0):
          typeId = "user"
        else:
          typeId = "group"
        postId = resp[i]['id']
        originalUrl = 'https://vk.com/'+resp[i][typeId]['screen_name']+'?w=wall'+str(curId)+'_'+str(postId)
        print originalUrl
        print resp[i]['text'].encode('cp866', errors='replace')
        print ''
```

Кроме того, если страница типа "public", то в "screen_name" все равно возвращается "clubXXX" и ссылка оказывается нерабочей.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить ссылку на оригинальный пост, достаточно знать id поста и id стены, на которую пост закинули.

Вот такая ссылка вполне работоспособна:
http://vk.com/wall-76229642_54082

Соответственно, нужно просто слегка подкорректировать код

```
originalUrl = 'https://vk.com/wall'+str(curId)+'_'+str(postId)
```